# how to do Ibatis version of show sql

Tags: java, ibatis

Is there an Ibatis setting to view the generated SQL like how Hibernate has show_sql=true?

thanks

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635058/ibatis-get-executed-sql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, turn up it's [logging level](http://ibatisnet.sourceforge.net/DevGuide.html#d0e2600).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Log it in your database server.

http://www.apachebookstore.com/confluence/oss/display/IBATIS/How+do+I+get+SqlMapClient+to+log+SQL+statements

[iBatis get executed sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635058/ibatis-get-executed-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [p6spy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/).

This is not *exactly* a Ibatis property setting to view the generated SQLs. p6spy is a kind of library you can easily plugin to your Java application.

It logs you the generated sql and also resultSet (Which is great, actually). I used for issue tracking in dynamic queries. It prints it in a log file.

This [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-solution/) blog may give you how-to integrate it with your Ibatis. (mkyong-blog-fan :))