# Do any techniques exist for visualizing (or at least documenting) iBatis Mappings?

Tags: java, ibatis

For those who have used iBatis - what techniques or tools do you typically use to visualize the data mappings between declarative XML, database tables / procedures, and Java objects? I haven't found any references on the web or in the documentation, and was curious whether good solutions exist. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the generated query and its parameter mapping then you can use Logging. iBatis support `Log4J` logging you can use that.It shows executing sql and other like that way in the logging area

```
Preparing Statement:  /*your query to be prepared */
Executing Statement:  /*your prepared query with parameter mapping* (wiht ?,?,?)/
Parameters:           /*Parameters mapped with the same sequence as `Executing Statement`*/
Types:                /*java types of the mapped parameter(example java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)*/
ResultSet:            /*ResultSet of the query (if any)*/
Result:               /*Rows of the ResultSet */
```

A documentation is in [this link](http://ibatisnet.sourceforge.net/DevGuide.html#d0e2600).
And a similar topic is in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635058/ibatis-get-executed-sql/3046502)