# Ibatis in .NET: get sql from sqlmap as string?

Tags: c#, sql, ibatis, ibatis.net

Is it possible to get sql in a sqlmap as a string?  There appears to be a way [with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635058/ibatis-get-executed-sql)?

So I have a sqlmap like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<sqlMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://ibatis.apache.org/mapping"
        namespace="PersonSqlMap">

  <statements>
    <select id="GetPersonByName" parameterClass="string" resultClass="Person">
      select * from PERSON P where P.Name = #Name#
    </select>
  </statements>

</sqlMap>
```

And in c# code I would like to get `"select * from PERSON P where P.Name = #Name#"`.